# Converting Varchar to Datetime on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

```
SELECT SubmitDate, Type, Location, CONVERT(DATETIME, SubmitDate, 101) AS DDate
FROM Employee
WHERE (Type IN ('C', 'Q')) 
  AND (DDate > DATEADD(DDate, - 1, GETDATE()))
```

I need to get all records from the past year, `SubmitDate` is a `varchar`. I use `CONVERT` to convert the column to `datetime`. However I am getting the following error:

> DDate Not recognizable dateadd option.

I tried switching the `CONVERT` to the following and it didn't work:

```
CONVERT(DATE, SubmitDate, 101)
```

Comment: You can't access an aliased/computed column within the where clause of the same level of query

Comment: Dateadd expects you to be telling it `what` you are adding as the first argument e.g. day, week (check the docs).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "from the past year"?   Do you mean from Jan 1 2018, or what?

Comment: It's likely the convert isn't your problem you've got a syntax issue with you dateadd. Argrument should be `DATEADD(Day, -1, GETDATE())` or whichever time interval you'd like to do.

Comment: Based on your comments you want `WHERE (Type IN ('C', 'Q')) A and CONVERT(datetime, SubmitDate, 101) > dateadd(year,-1,getdate())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As users have commented above, you cannot reference column aliases in WHERE clauses on your query. You can, however, use the column transformation in the WHERE clause. It isn't very efficient, but if you're using the query once or twice (IE: Not in a SSIS package or automated task) it should be alright.

```
SELECT SubmitDate, Type, Location,CONVERT(datetime, SubmitDate, 101) AS DDate
FROM Employee
WHERE ([Type] IN ('C', 'Q')) 
AND (CONVERT(datetime, SubmitDate, 101) > DATEADD(Day, - 1, GETDATE()))
```

The second problem with your query is the DATEADD clause. DATEADD requires three paramaters: The datepart, the number, and the date. You have an invalid datepart, or "what part of the date are you performing the arithmetic on". `DDate` is not a datepart, it's a column. A datepart is values like Month, Day, Year, Week, etc.
I edited the query to set the datepart to "Day" so the clause will evaluate (using pseduocode) `GETDATE()-1 Day`, but you can set it to `GETDATE()-1 Month`, or hour. But the current psedocode expression of `GETDATE()-1 DDate` doesn't make sense to your SQL Server client

[Refer to Microsoft documentation for more DATEADD information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Cool you fixed yours so I'll delete mine. No point in having two answers to the same problem.